# Do SOAP properties always occur in the same order?

Tags: java, android, soap, ksoap2

I am using ksoap2 to access an Azure service and I need to get properties out of a fairly complex object.  It looks a bit like

```
<a:top xmlns:a="http://anamespace.org/" xmlns:b="http://bnamespace.org">
    <b:middle>
        <b:bottom>value</b:bottom>
        <b:derriere>value2</b:derriere>
    </b:middle>
    <b:muddle>other</b:muddle>
</a:top>
```

Now I want to get the properties by name, but `SoapObject.getProperty(String)` doesn't seem to let you specify a namespace.  The sub-elements have a different namespace from the top element.  On the other hand, declaring a `KVMSerializable` object seems to assume that properties can be put into the object *by index and in order*.  However, my experience of XML suggests that

```
<a:top xmlns:a="http://anamespace.org/" xmlns:b="http://bnamespace.org">
    <b:muddle>other</b:muddle>
    <b:middle>
        <b:bottom>value</b:bottom>
        <b:derriere>value2</b:derriere>
    </b:middle>
</a:top>
```

is usually just as valid.  Is this untrue for SOAP?  Do SOAP elements always occur in only one order, and can this be relied upon completely?

Answer (score 1):

With the latest 2.6.1 release of ksoap2-android I cut yesterday ordering becomes significant. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks—is that documented somewhere? However I'm interested in whether a SOAP service will always produce SOAP properties in the same order, so that you can rely on that ordering when defining a ksoap2 setup with `KVMSerializable`.